# Immutable mergeIn overwrites the original values

Tags: immutable.js

I've got a problem when using Immutable.js with nested map and list, I was expected `mergeIn` will merge the new value with the old one, however it overwrite the value instead.

How to get it correctly?

```
const state = fromJS({
  list: []
})
  .update("list", l => l.push({ a: 1 }))
  .mergeIn(["list", 0], { b: 3 })
  .getIn(["list", 0])
```

I was expecting the final value is `{ a: 1, b: 3 }`, however, the actual output is `{ b: 3 }`

Answer (score 1):

Immutable.js is not supposed to merge plain objects like that (prior to v4 anyway).

```
state.mergeIn(["list", 0], { b: 3 })
```

is equivalent to

```
state.updateIn(["list", 0], m => m.merge({ b: 3 }))
```

When the updater function of `.updateIn()` is called, since `{ a : 1}` has no `merge()` method in its prototype, Immutable.js doesn't merge it but replaces with the new object instead.

You can fix this if you just make an Immutable.Map out of `{a : 1}`. Or use Immutable.js v4+: apparently, it uses [`Immutable.merge()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/merge) to merge plain objects, exactly the way you expected it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it with immutableJS v4.0.0-rc.12 and it works as you expected, i.e. `{ a: 1, b: 3 }`. So maybe you just have to update to that version